# How to concatenate multiple numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 3 arrays containing numbers into a seperate array containing all of these.

I don't want to force the numbers into a string, as I need to use a script to compare the elements of the currentdate array to find the largest one.

**(e.g. if currentdate[0] > currentdate[1], where currentdate[0] will equal 11122014 and currentdate[1] will equal 13122014).**

is there an alternative that does so?

Here is my code:

```
var currentdate = new Array();
{
currentdate[0] = currentday[0].concat(currentmonth[0],currentyear[0] );
currentdate[1] = currentday[1].concat(currentmonth[1],currentyear[1] );
currentdate[2] = currentday[2].concat(currentmonth[2],currentyear[2] );
currentdate[3] = currentday[3].concat(currentmonth[3],currentyear[3] );
currentdate[4] = currentday[4].concat(currentmonth[4],currentyear[4] );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you plan on comparing dates with different months or years with this format?

Comment: Is date a red herring?  Otherwise, it would be much more natural to either convert a date tuple into its corresponding number of seconds (integer) or at least into YYYYmmDD formated string, both of which allows for easy comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
 currentdate[0] =  parseInt('' + currentday[0] + currentmonth[0] + currentyear[0])
```